# I came across this method but I can read def genres but I cant get the (&:genre)

Tags: ruby

I came across this method but I can't read the bit (&:genre). So basically I don't know what it means.

```rb
def genres
  songs.map(&:genre)
end

thanks
```

Comment: It's a shortcut for `songs.map { |song| song.genre }`

Comment: thank you for the help